# change a class using angular ng-click and ng-class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a series of menu items with submenus and they all have an angle-down icon that it's supposed to flip upwards using a class `rotate180`. Problem is, I can't isolate the functionality so that it only happens in the menu I am opening and not all of them. ALSO, I need it to stay in the desired position according to the menu being open or closed. By either opening/closing the menu on clicking it or by canceling the icon flip once menu is opened. Hope that makes sense.

Here is my html

```
<div class="menu-item">
    <md-list id="playerTrigger" ng-click="menuIsOpen = 1; changeClass()" layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="center center" flex>
        <span class="title flex" flex=""> Players</span>
        <span ng-class="class"></span>
    </md-list>
    <div class="sub-menu" ng-show="menuIsOpen===1" ng-animate="'animate'">
        <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in vm.players">
            <md-button>
                <div layout="row" flex="">
                    <a ui-sref="{{item.linkto}}" class="">
                        <p flex="">{{item.title}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the controller

```js
$scope.class = "ti-icon ti-mini right ti-angle-down";
$scope.changeClass = function() {
  if ($scope.class === "ti-icon ti-mini right ti-angle-down")
      $scope.class = "ti-icon ti-mini right ti-angle-down rotate180";
  else
      $scope.class = "ti-icon ti-mini right ti-angle-down";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to toggle `rotate180` class, I would keep the static classes in `class` attribute and the changing one in `ng-class`:

```
<span class="ti-icon ti-mini right ti-angle-down" ng-class="{'rotate180': rotate}"></span>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.rotate = false; //initial value 
$scope.changeClass = function() { 
     $scope.rotate = !$scope.rotate;
}
```

Comment: Indeed a cleaner way to add the class but this does exactly what my code does, just cleaner. The changeClass() is triggering this flip and it's being called on every menu item. So when I click on one it does it all menu items. I'm looking for an isolated way of doing this to only the menu item that is being clicked on without creating a function for each item

Comment: You could also have done it without any property or method on the controller using `ng-init` and `ng-click` which I think sometimes is better as it leave the controller code lighter and cleaner.